# oracle datasource unknown source in jenkins pipeline groovy script

Tags: oracle, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to execute an sql query from pipeline script in jenkins using groovy,
but it is not able to resolve the oracle datasource (oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource). Please let me know how can I make this work.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

    def parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
    def loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent)

   def ConfigEntityObj
   def ServiceEntityObj   
   def DBConnClassObj
   def TibcoServiceXMLClassObj
   String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource";
   Class.forName(driverName);

    ConfigEntityObj = loader.parseClass(new File("D://Pedda//Tibco_Automation//src//com//merck//Entity//ConfigEntity.java")).newInstance()
    ServiceEntityObj = loader.parseClass(new File("D://Pedda//Tibco_Automation//src//com//merck//Entity//ServiceEntity.java")).newInstance()    
    DBConnClassObj = loader.parseClass(new File("D://Pedda//Tibco_Automation//src//com//merck//comet//DBConnectionManager.groovy")).newInstance()
    TibcoServiceXMLClassObj = loader.parseClass(new File("D://Pedda//Tibco_Automation//src//com//merck//comet//TibcoServiceXML.groovy")).newInstance()

    TibcoServiceXMLClassObj.callSQL()



public void callSQL() {

    try {

        def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:oracle:thin:@DS-3860778D2AF5:1521:xe', 'tibco_automation', 'tibco_automation', 'oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource')

        sql.query('select * from ISS_APPS_INVENTORY') { resultSet ->
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                println "hi"
                println resultSet.getString(1)
            }

            File file1 = new File("D://Pedda//ResultSet.txt");
            file1.write(resultSet.getString(1))


        }

    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace()
        File file = new File("D://Pedda//SQL.txt");
        file.write(e.getMessage()+ " Exception "+e.getStackTrace())

    }
}
```

Exception as below.

```
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceException [java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source), 
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450), 
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403), 
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method), 
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source), groovy.sql.Sql.loadDriver(Sql.java:705), 
groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:445), 
groovy.sql.Sql$newInstance.call(Unknown Source), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149), 
com.merck.comet.DBConnectionManager.getServiceList(DBConnectionManager.groovy:84), 
com.merck.comet.DBConnectionManager$getServiceList$0.call(Unknown Source), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125), 
com.merck.comet.TibcoServiceXML.createServiceXML(TibcoServiceXML.groovy:34), 
com.merck.comet.TibcoServiceXML$createServiceXML.call(Unknown Source), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:15), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:55), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:74), 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor692.invoke(Unknown Source), 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:297), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:78), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:206), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:204), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47), 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source), 
hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112), 
jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28), 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source), 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source), 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source), 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Again its a case of adding the jars in appropriate location, in my local, Jenkins is running as standalone. In server it is running in Tomcat, so I had to add the jar files in Jenkins->Apache-tomcat->bin.